# VBA MS-Word: Is it possible to replace text with wildcard?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible to replace the text that was found using wildcard and replace it with wildcard also? for example `FindText:="(^13{2}*^13)", Forward:=True, MatchWildcards:=True,` then replace it with wildcard like this `replacewith:="(^13{2}*^11)"`. Is it possible?

Comment: Not really sure, but what does the find return?  Does it return anything to do with position in the doc, like excel returns a range when using find?

Comment: here's an example, it will return something like this "^p^psomethingword^p" it will select it.

Comment: the "^p" is a carriage return
"

Comment: So what is it you want, i understood it as you want to find and replace wildcard entries, with the wildcard used to find them.  If it is then the result of the .find.... will return where they are.

Comment: Exactly, but unlike the excel that it return's the position of the matched string, in word, it will highlight the first occurrence of the string and unlike excel that it returns something like you said "A1", in word, it will not return where it is exactly like the number of line where it was or paragraph but simple it will just highlight the text. It doesn't return any specific position unlike excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire discussion in Comments is unclear, but I understand that you need to replace only part of the search term, and retain another part. Yes, that's possible by defining *expressions* in the search term. For example:

Find: "(^13{2}*)^13"
Replace: \1^11

An expression is defined using parentheses. You can have multiple expressions in the "Find" text. Refer to an expression and have Word use it in the replacement using backslash+index, where index is the number (location) of the expression in the Find text. In the above example, taken from your question, there is one expression, so \1.

Comment: Wow! That's the exact answer I was looking for. Thank you very much for understanding my question crystal clear. I didn't know that I can define a number of expression using "()" and call that using index in the replace part. You're right about the discussion in the comment, it is so irrelevant and almost out of bound. Thank you once again for understanding my question clearly.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a word developer, but just done this, not complete solution, but a good starting point??? :  Text was "Nathan testing Nathan testing"

```
        dim x as find    

    Selection.WholeStory

            Set x = Selection.Find
 x.Find.ClearFormatting
            x.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
            With x
                .Text = "Na*han"
                .Replacement.Text = .Text
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindAsk
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchWildcards = True
            End With

            x.Execute
            x.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
```